# Why doesn't strip method in python take the two "\n" in a text file

Tags: python

```
import pdb
input_file_eng = open('engltreaty.txt')
word_list_eng = input_file_eng.read()
pure_word_list_eng = word_list_eng.strip("\n").strip("\r").strip('-').strip('.').strip(',').strip('(').strip(')').strip('[').strip(']')
pdb.set_trace()
input_file_eng.close()
```

and at the break point, I inspect the string pure_word_list_eng, it still contains '[',']',"\n" "\n\n"

and I below is the text file:

> HER MAJESTY VICTORIA Queen of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and
>   Ireland regarding with Her Royal Favour the Native Chiefs and Tribes
>   of New Zealand and anxious to protect their just Rights and Property
>   and to secure to them the enjoyment of Peace and Good Order has deemed
>   it necessary in consequence of the great number of Her Majesty's
>   Subjects who have already settled in New Zealand and the rapid
>   extension of Emigration both from Europe and Australia which is still
>   in progress to constitute and appoint a functionary properly
>   authorised to treat with the Aborigines of New Zealand for the
>   recognition of Her Majesty's Sovereign authority over the whole or any
>   part of those islands - Her Majesty therefore being desirous to
>   establish a settled form of Civil Government with a view to avert the
>   evil consequences which must result from the absence of the necessary
>   Laws and Institutions alike to the native population and to Her
>   subjects has been graciously pleased to empower and to authorise me
>   William Hobson a Captain in Her Majesty's Royal Navy Consul and
>   Lieutenant-Governor of such parts of New Zealand as may be or
>   hereafter shall be ceded to her Majesty to invite the confederated and
>   independent Chiefs of New Zealand to concur in the following Articles
>   and Conditions.
>
> Article the first [Article 1] The Chiefs of the Confederation of the
>   United Tribes of New Zealand and the separate and independent Chiefs
>   who have not become members of the Confederation cede to Her Majesty
>   the Queen of England absolutely and without reservation all the rights
>   and powers of Sovereignty which the said Confederation or Individual
>   Chiefs respectively exercise or possess, or may be supposed to
>   exercise or to possess over their respective Territories as the sole
>   sovereigns thereof.
>
> Article the second [Article 2] Her Majesty the Queen of England
>   confirms and guarantees to the Chiefs and Tribes of New Zealand and to
>   the respective families and individuals thereof the full exclusive and
>   undisturbed possession of their Lands and Estates Forests Fisheries
>   and other properties which they may collectively or individually
>   possess so long as it is their wish and desire to retain the same in
>   their possession; but the Chiefs of the United Tribes and the
>   individual Chiefs yield to Her Majesty the exclusive right of
>   Preemption over such lands as the proprietors thereof may be disposed
>   to alienate at such prices as may be agreed upon between the
>   respective Proprietors and persons appointed by Her Majesty to treat
>   with them in that behalf.
>
> Article the third [Article 3] In consideration thereof Her Majesty the
>   Queen of England extends to the Natives of New Zealand Her royal
>   protection and imparts to them all the Rights and Privileges of
>   British Subjects.
>
> (signed) William Hobson, Lieutenant-Governor.
>
> Now therefore We the Chiefs of the Confederation of the United Tribes
>   of New Zealand being assembled in Congress at Victoria in Waitangi and
>   We the Separate and Independent Chiefs of New Zealand claiming
>   authority over the Tribes and Territories which are specified after
>   our respective names, having been made fully to understand the
>   Provisions of the foregoing Treaty, accept and enter into the same in
>   the full spirit and meaning thereof in witness of which we have
>   attached our signatures or marks at the places and the dates
>   respectively specified. Done at Waitangi this Sixth day of February in
>   the year of Our Lord one thousand eight hundred and forty.

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer: note that strip('\n\r-.,()[]') is usually more appropriate than chaining strip functions (but not equivalent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> Return a copy of the string **with the leading and trailing characters removed**.

Try `str.replace()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate)

> string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])
>   Delete all characters from s
>   that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the
>   characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving
>   the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If
>   table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.

so

```
pure_word_list_eng = word_list_eng.translate(None, "\n\r-.,()[]")
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out `translate` method, it's the choice to replace multiply characters

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Ignacio, `str.strip()` only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string.  You should use `str.replace()`, or this alternative using regular expressions:

```
import re
pure_word_list_eng = re.sub(r'[-\n\r.,()]+', '', word_list_eng)
```

Comment: +1 for rephrasing the `with the leading and trailing characters removed.` sometimes I can't figure out the English explanation right away